# Called to undefined method laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I installed the backpack-demo package and was able to register a new user.
Now when I want to add a new permission role or something else that needs to insert a new record into the DB i got the following error message:
"BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getCastedAttributes()"

Any idea how to solve?

thx,
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an error that has already been fixed. A composer update should fix it for you.